# Java, code works, but exception is still thrown

Tags: java, sql, exception

I am creating a simple registration frame that adds records onto a database. It gives me an error message every time it runs the SQL query that adds records in the database, however it still adds them, but because of that my programs gets to a standstill, instead of opening another window.

here's that part of the code:

```
regButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

@Override public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
   //Execute when button is pressed
   if(   uNameField.getText().equals("")
      || new String(newPassField.getPassword()).equals("")
      || new String(repeatPassField.getPassword()).equals("") ) {
      errorLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
      errorLabel.setText("Some fields are left blank");
   }
   else if( new String(newPassField.getPassword()).equals(
            new String(repeatPassField.getPassword()))){
      Statement stmt;
      ResultSet res;
      try
      {
         //SET USERNAME AND PASSWORD FROM FIELDS TO UPPER CASE
         String username = uNameField.getText().toUpperCase();
         String password = new String(newPassField.getPassword()).toUpperCase();
         //SQL INSERT QUERY
         String sql;
         sql = "INSERT INTO Employees VALUES ('" +username +"','" +password +"');";
         stmt = con.createStatement();
         res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
         System.out.println("Added to database!");
         con.close();
      }
      catch(SQLException exe) {
         System.out.println("Error creating or running statement: " + e.toString());
         try {
            con.close();
         }
         catch(Exception eex){}
      }
   }
   else {
      errorLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
      errorLabel.setText("Password missmatch");
   }
}
```

Every time it registers a new employee (user) it displays this "Error creating or running statement: ..... " although, I can find the newly added employees in the employee list.

What may be causing this problem?

Comment: Could you print the stack trace of the Exception(s) you're swallowing and add it to your question?

Comment: can you please print the stacktrace by using variable `exe`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [executeUpdate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String%29) for SQL INSERTs

```
int rowCount = stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Comment: When I change it, I get an error on that line saying "incompatible types, required java.sql.ResultSet, found Int

Answer (score 4):

Before we get to your specific problem, some general advice:

```
Connection con = ...
try {
    // your stuff
}
catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
  try {
    con.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

The way you are doing it now not only swallows the exception, but also avoids printing its stacktrace. And `close` must be performend once and only once, regardless of the exception.

If you are on Java 7, this would be much easier:

```
try (Connetion con = ...) {
  // stuff to do
}
catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The closing in a `finally` is now done automatically.

Specifically about your exception, you execute an INSERT by calling `executeQuery`. This method sends the statement to the DB, which properly executes it, but its response back to the JDBC is not a ResultSet. This is where it blows up, **after the record is already inserted**. Since you are in autocommit mode, there is no transaction to roll back. Lesson: **always use transactions**.

Comment: @Aubin Sure, if it's available to OP.

Answer (score 1):

I hate seeing code written this way.  You didn't ask about this, and my comment won't solve your problem, but I think it needs to be said.

You're creating a maintenance nightmare for yourself by putting persistence code in a Swing Listener method.

A better idea is to think about objects in a way that gives them a single responsibility.

Take your persistence code and move it into a separate class that you can develop and test on its own.  Once it's working, give a reference to the class that needs it.

Your code will be more modular, easier to test, more reusable, and less of a nightmare to understand.

Uncle Bob Martin has a succinct mneumonic for this and other ideas worth remembering: [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29).

Comment: In all probability, there will be no maintenance of this code, but it's never too early to start learning the right way.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you try PreparedStatement

```
try{
    //SET USERNAME AND PASSWORD FROM FIELDS TO UPPER CASE
     String username = uNameField.getText().toUpperCase();
     String password = new String(newPassField.getPassword()).toUpperCase();
     //SQL INSERT QUERY
     PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("insert into Employees values(?,?)");
     pstmt.setString(1,username);
     pstmt.setString(2,password);

     if(!pstmt.execute())
     {
       //means your code worked correctly
        System.out.println("Inserted successfully");
     }
     else
     {
           System.out.println("Unsuccessfull");
     }
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
      ex.printStackTrace();
   }
```